# create New worksheet (Tab) with name from specific column if that name doesn't exists

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel with master sheet `TAB#1` of employee's name, its data range is `B1:B100`.

When I add a new employee name in another sheet `TAB#2` which data range is `C1:C50`, the macro should search in `TAB#1` with a data range of `C1:C50` if the name entered in the `TAB#2` doesn't exists already in the `TAB#1`. It should create a new worksheet and name it with the name of new employee which is given in `TAB#2`.

Is this possible? can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You need to add it in your `Tab #2` sheet in the VBeditor.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim inputRange As Range, names As Range, found As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set inputRange = Worksheets("Tab #2").Range("C1:C50")
    Set names = Worksheets("Master").Range("B1:B100")

    If Not Intersect(Target, inputRange) Is Nothing Then
        Set found = names.Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            ws.name = Target
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```